# PHP SQL MYSQL database name have bash (-) use group_concat can't print correct data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

database

```
ID name-04 data-05 
1  The    CAT
2  Ring   Some
3  The    Dog
```

I am use `GROUP_CONCAT(name-04 order by ID SEPARATOR ',')`
Output are not correct will display null.
If use `GROUP_CONCAT('name-04' order by ID SEPARATOR ',')`
will display `name-04 name-04`
How to fix....
My database have to need bash (-) ....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMneN.png)

Comment: You need to use backticks when enclosing field names in MySQL.

Comment: PHP can't use " name-A"

Comment: Should be something like `GROUP_CONCAT(\`name-01\` order by ID SEPARATOR ',')`

Comment: I am use 'name-01' will display name-01 name-01 not my correct data....

Comment: Is there any PHP code you want to share? You haven't provided any parts where any output displays "null"